# Path-based routing to multiple backends serving subsequent content from identical paths

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-gateway

*my-domain.com* (a web application service) is exposed through an Azure Application Gateway (v2).
Using path-based routing, I'm also exposing other web applications on select paths.

For example:

- *my-domain.com/app-1* points to the backend *my-first-app.azurewebsites.net* .
- *my-domain.com/app-2* points to the backend *my-second-app.azurewebsites.net* .

So far, so good. But, both of these web applications serve dynamic content on the path */static**, which in turn resolves to *my-domain.com/static**. If there only was one web app, I could reroute everything from *my-domain.com/static** to the correct backend i.e. *my-first-app.azurewebsites.net/static**, but I'm struggling coming up with a solution when I have multiple web applications behind the same domain like this. Both backends now resolve continuous content requests to *my-domain.com/static**, but I can't route them correctly to a backend as I have no way of differentiating them in the gateway configuration (that I know of, rules only look at paths).

I've looked into using a rewrite set as well for this, but I haven't found a way to properly route requests to backends from there.

Is this doable for the configuration above? I've had to resolve to using subdomains of my-domain.com for now, but I'm curious if this is possible with the setup above.

Answer (score 0):

Path base routing to multiple backends.

1. Create two vm.
2. Create application gateway.
   [image]
   [image]

[image]

[image]

Add routing rule.
[image]

[image]

[image]

After successfully add routing rule
open url _http://:8080/nameyouuse

For more information read this microsoft document on  [Create an application gateway with path-based routing rules using the Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/create-url-route-portal)

Comment: Thanks for answering, but unfortunately this doesn't answer my question. I'm familiar with the common scenarios of path-based routing, which seems to be what you are describing. Please read my question again.

Comment: @jH- from single doman you can't directly reroute any applications.